# PHP checking if method_exists using an variable obtained by function calls

Tags: php, function, call

The following try..catch is meant to run a method if it exists and run a different method if it doesn't..

```
        $heading = new HeadingMan();
        try {
            if (!is_callable($heading->{$this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3)}())) {
                throw new Exception ('<b>Error - HeadingMan class can not handle: </b>' . $this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3));
            }
            $heading->{$this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3)};
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $heading->latest();
        }
```

However, the catch statement always triggers, and throws a new exception (runs the catch portion of the statement).

How do I check a method exists in a class by using a series of function calls

```
$this->breadcrumbs->getCrumb(3);
```

to get the name of the function.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$bool = method_exists($class,$method);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php